# How to create adjacency matrix for gene-gene interactions from RNA-Seq (circlize input)

Tags: r, data-visualization, adjacency-matrix, chord-diagram, circlize

I'm profiling tumor microenvironment and I want to show interactions between subpopulations that I found. I have a list of receptors and ligands for example, and I want to show that population A expresses ligand 1 and population C expresses receptor 1 so there's likely an interaction between these two populations through the expression of ligand-receptor 1.

I have been trying to use circlize to visualize these interactions by making a `chordDiagram`, but it requires an adjacency matrix as input and I do not understand how to create the matrix. The adjacency matrix is supposed to show the strength of the relationship between any two genes in my matrix. I have 6 unique populations of cells that can express any of the 485 ligands/receptors that I am interested in, and the goal is to show interactions between these populations through the ligands and receptors.

I found a tool to use in RStudio called BUS- gene.similarity: Calculate adjacency matrix for gene-gene interaction.

Maybe I am just using BUS incorrectly but it says: For gene expression data with M genes and N experiments, the adjacency matrix is in size of MxM. An adjacency matrix in size of MxM with rows and columns both standing for genes. Element in row i and column j indicates the similarity between gene i and gene j.

So, I made a matrix where each column is a subpopulation and each row is a ligand/receptor I want to show interactions with. The cells have expression values and it looks like this:

```
> head(Test)
            A          B           C          D           E           F
Adam10 440.755990 669.875468 748.7313995 702.991422 1872.033343 2515.074366
Adam17 369.813134 292.625603 363.0301707 434.905968 1183.152694 1375.424034
Agt     12.676036  28.269671   9.2428034  19.920561  121.587010  168.116735
Angpt1  22.807415  42.350205  25.5464603  16.010813  194.620550   99.383567
Angpt2  92.492760 186.167844 819.3679836 852.666499  669.642441 1608.748788
Angpt4   3.327743   0.693985   0.8292746   1.112826    5.463647    5.826927
```

Where A-F are my populations. Then I pass this matrix to BUS:

```
res<-gene.similarity(Test,measure="corr",net.trim="none")

Warning message:
In cor(mat) : the standard deviation is zero
```

But the output file which is supposed to be my adjacency matrix is full of NA's:

```
         Adam10 Adam17 
Adam10      1     NA
Adam17     NA     1
```

I thought maybe my matrix was too complex, so I compared only 2 cell populations with my ligands/receptors, but I get the exact same output.

I was expecting to get something like:

```
         A:Adam10 A:Adam17 
C:Adam10     6       1 
E:Adam17     2      10
```

But, even if the `res` object gave me numbers instead of `NA` it does not maintain the identity of the population when making relationships amongst genes so it still would not produce my expected output.

I do not have to use BUS to make the matrix, so I don't necessarily need help troubleshooting that code, I just need SOME way to make an adjacency matrix.

I've never used circlize or Circos before so I apologize if my question is stupid.

Comment: 1) Check that none of your rows are a singular value. 2) Your expected output should be cell populations not genes so should be A-F. Yes the resulting matrix does not keep the colnames but you can add those back from `Test`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to transform you matrix a little.
you can create a new matrix which has size (nrow(Test) x ncol(Text)) x (nrow(Test) x ncol(Text)), so in the example you gave, the new matrix will be 36x36, and the colnames and rownames will be the same which are A_Adam10, A_Adam17,..., A_Angpt4, B_Adam10,..., F_Angpt4.
With the help of a loop, you can load the similarity of each pair into the new matrix, and now you can plot the matrix. It's a little complicated, also takes a while to run the loop, but it's intuitive.
You're welcomed to check my [github repo](https://github.com/timxymo/Chord-Diagram-Visualization) since I had a similar problem not too long ago, and I posted detailed code on there. I hope this will help you